# ionic react android won't run after following the steps

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, ionic-framework

After starting an ionic react app and not changing the default code, which runs without an error on the web,
I tried the steps on [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/android/). and everything went okay and I got my app built, until I tried running it on android studio and I got the following errors:

> `Object.assign` is not a function.
>
> `Array.from` is not a function.

and my app just opened a white screen.

After I searched I discovered these are codes for ES6 so how do I solve it!

Comment: It looks like those functions are not in the browser, maybe you have an old version that doesnt support ES6. At any case you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) resource that will help you solve this compatibility issue.

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I didn't change the default code initially provided for blank project, it is caused by one of the chunk js files, I just don't know how to make the es 6 codes run. and by old version what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Im not sure check your browser version and see if it supports `ES6`

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I'm trying to run it on android natively using capacitor so, what browser version should I check?